# Where to find sharing option in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently working on vs code with version 1.8. Recently microsoft introduce new feature which called **Visual studio Live Share**.My problem is that I am not able to find **sharing** button or menu/submenu.

If you have any idea where to find or how to share code using vs code.please help me.

Comment: Sign up for the preview coming later: https://code.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-live-share

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few month later (from Nov. 2017 to May 2018), the Live Share feature is now ready: see "[Visual Studio Live Share Public Preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/05/07/live-share-public-preview)", and "[Visual Studio Live Share](https://www.visualstudio.com/services/live-share/)" to download the extension.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/) explains, for [Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#share-a-project), how to share:

> ### Start a collaboration session
>
> Now, simply click the "Share" status bar item or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select "Live Share: Start a collaboration session (Share)".

[image: Share button: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/media/vscode-share-button.png]

> Note: You may be asked by your desktop firewall software to allow the Live Share agent to open a port the first time you share. Accepting this is entirely optional but enables a secured "direct mode" to improve performance when the person you are working with is on the same network as you are.
>   See [changing the connection mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/connectivity#changing-the-connection-mode) for details.
>
> An invite link will be automatically copied to your clipboard.
>   When opened in a browser, this link allows others to join a new collaboration session that shares contents of these folders with them.
>
> You will also see the "Share" status bar item transition to represent the session state. See **[session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#session-states)** information below for what this looks like.
>
> Note that if you need to get the invite link again after you've started sharing, you access it again by clicking on the session state status bar icon and select "`Invite Others (Copy Link)`".